# requiring min 1 out of 3 form input fields

Tags: html, forms, input

i am making a database programm where the user has to submit some of his contact information.

```
 <form action="add_action.php" method="POST">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    Name: <br>
                    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" required><br>
                    Telefon Nr. <br>
                    <input type="text" name="telNr" placeholder="Telefon Nr."><br>
                    Handy Nr. <br>
                    <input type="text" name="handyNr" placeholder="Handy Nr."><br>
                    Skype ID <br>
                    <input type="text" name="skypeId" placeholder="Skype ID"><br>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Hinzufügen">
                </div>
            </form>
```

i have been researching a while now, but i cant seem to figure out how i can set the form so at least 1 out of "Telefon Nr.", "Handy Nr." and "Skype ID" is required. if you have any sugestions of what i should do i would apreciate your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider reading this. I'll be showing, only, how to check for the presence of the field named `name` alongside at least one field from the others.

**Sever side verification:**

*Ps: you didn't give the submit `button` a `name`, i'll give it a `name="submit"`, for example, to make checking for form submission possible within `php`.*

```
if{isset($_POST["submit"])
    // don't rely on HTML required attribute, a user with a bit of knowledge can remove/bypass it, I mean check for the presence of the name either
    $name = trim($_POST["name"]);
    $telNr = trim($_POST["telNr"]);
    $handyNr = trim($_POST["handyNr"]);
    $skypeId = trim($_POST["skypeId"]);
    if(isset($name[0]) && (isset($telNr[0]) || isset($handyNr[0]) || isset($skypeId[0]))) {
        echo "At least one field is present alongside with the name";
    } else {
        echo "The name and/or the other fields are empty";
    }
}
```

**Client side verification:**

*Ps:* let me give an `ID` to the `form` tag, let's say `id="my-form"`.

```
var myForm = document.getElementById("my-form");
myForm.addEventListener("submit", function(event){
    // get all the fields values, and trim them on the fly
     var name = document.getElementsByName("name")[0].value().trim(),
         telNr = document.getElementsByName("telNr")[0].value().trim(),
         handyNr = document.getElementsByName("handyNr")[0].value().trim(), 
         skypeId = document.getElementsByName("skypeId")[0].value().trim();
     // we want the name and at least one other field to be filled
     if(name !== "" && (telNr !== "" || handyNr !== "" || skypeId !== "" )) {
         alert("we're good to go, the name is provided alongside with at least another field");
     } else {
         event.preventDefault(); // we cancel form submission as the name and/or the other fields are empty using the Event argument
         alert("Cancelled, please fill in the name and at least one other field");
     }
});
```

Hope I pushed you further to more understand how things work

**Ps:** that's a really basic example, don't rely on this in production phase as the code I provided may be vulnerable to some attacks(such as XSS aka Cross-Site-Scripting, SQL injection...).

Comment: Thank you very much. this helped me out with the problem i had. and i learned a few new things.

Comment: You're welcome at any time  ! Glad I helped you, that's an honor for me.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to use some javascript to do this. The only thing you can do with HTML is add the "required" attribute as you've done with the name already.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way i created it in a form i made a while back. I have edited it for you so place it in and should work off the bat.

```
<script>
function validateForm() {
    var a,b,c,d = document.forms["form"]["name","telNr","handyNr","skypeId"].value;
    if (a,b,c,d==null || a,b,c,d=="")
  {
  alert("Please complete all Required Fields *");
  return false;
  }
    }
</script>

<body>

<form name="form" action="add_action.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="POST">

                <div class="modal-body">

                    Name: <br>
                    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name"><br>

                    Telefon Nr. <br>
                    <input type="text" name="telNr" placeholder="Telefon Nr."><br>

                    Handy Nr. <br>
                    <input type="text" name="handyNr" placeholder="Handy Nr."><br>

                    Skype ID <br>
                    <input type="text" name="skypeId" placeholder="Skype ID"><br>

                <div class="modal-footer">

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Hinzufügen" >Sign In</button>


                </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but the code you have written unfortunately doesnt work for me, because it sets all the fields to required.

Comment: Sorry about that i will go back and hopefully find you a solution